# Dimension of the bias vector in tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I was experimenting on `tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM` and realized the dimension of the bias size is `[8 * num_units,]`. ([Source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a6d8ffae097d0132989ae4688d224121ec6d8f35/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/cudnn_recurrent.py#L449))

```
import tensorflow as tf

#Data Parameters
num_timesteps = 24
num_features = 33

#Network Parameters
num_units = 2048

inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_timesteps, num_features])
LSTM1 = tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(units = num_units, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', recurrent_initializer='orthogonal', bias_initializer='zeros', unit_forget_bias=True, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)(inputs)
#<tf.Tensor 'cu_dnnlstm_1/transpose_1:0' shape=(?, 24, 2048) dtype=float32>

tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)
#[<tf.Variable 'cu_dnnlstm/kernel:0' shape=(33, 8192) dtype=float32>,
# <tf.Variable 'cu_dnnlstm/recurrent_kernel:0' shape=(2048, 8192) dtype=float32>,
# <tf.Variable 'cu_dnnlstm/bias:0' shape=(16384,) dtype=float32>]
```

However, if you look at the formulation of LSTM Block, there is only 4 weights for each of the gate and block input.

[image]

The only assumption I have they also implemented bias vectors separately for both input and recurrent weights, however, I could not find a reference to it.

Comment: Yeah you are right it is a separate bias for the recurrent kernel. Here is a [github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8860#issuecomment-393725837) about it.

Comment: Yes, I knew it! I still do not understand why it has been implemented like that but understandable inputs must also have biases. I found this page but did not scroll all the way down! I missed the actual answer! Thank you very much!

Comment: because the implementation is rewritten. if you look at the LSTM source code of Keras, it calls upon the base LSTMCell implementation, which does not use separate biases for a recurrent kernel. This might be probably why it is so here.

Comment: I could not understand what you mean. This is the case for all TF LSTM implementations (only one bias vector for each gates and block input) but just not with this one.

Comment: I meant if you look at the [LSTM](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a6d8ffae097d0132989ae4688d224121ec6d8f35/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L2100) source code, it calls LSTMCell, which is kind of a base class which does not have separate bias. Here since its done from scratch, they have it different.

Comment: Strange it is. yes, `tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell` does not have separate bias. [This](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a6d8ffae097d0132989ae4688d224121ec6d8f35/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1829) is how I realized the difference between these two classes, let alone knowing about LSTM equations.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2X bias in `CuDNNLSTM`, but the way it is implemented in `Tensorflow` is different.
As per [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/fcc4b966f1265f466e82617020af93670141b009/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent_v2.py#L789) code it is written in such a way that it does not makes use of separate bias for a `recurrent kernel` instead it calls `LSTMCell` which is a base class.